# PyQt5 gif not Showing up

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, gif, animated-gif

So here is my code(simplified):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QPropertyAnimation, QRect
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from pathlib import Path

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        loadUi("test.ui", self)

        self.movie = QMovie("GIF.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is my UI file(simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>240</x>
      <y>200</y>
      <width>371</width>
      <height>151</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

It is supposed to load a UI file and show a gif. It loads a UI successfully but only the left, unanimated part of the gif is showing and the rest is not showing. I would be very thankful if someone can help me. It tells me that I need to add more details but there are no, if you need some kind of information, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the ui file as well?

Comment: It says that it is too big.

Comment: Just make a minimum example with the key components to show the gif image and remove everything else...

Comment: I added a UI file.

Comment: Thanks. I ran your code but I could not reproduce the problem, the GIF file is animated when I run it.

Comment: It is probably because of gif file

Comment: Ensure that the file name is correct (check its case also), that it's in the same path as your script and that you're running the script from there. Then check with another gif file, in case yours is corrupted or it simply is not an animated one.